# Regression or Prediction Equation

Tags: regression, prediction

How do you determine whuch is x and y axis if the given problem is: A group of 12 respondents was given a 150-item mental ability test. The socioeconomic status of theses respondents was based on a continuous rating scale of 10.

Answer (score 0):

In the usual notation, $y$ is the variable you want to predict from the known variable $x$. Then, your choice depends on your goal.

If you want to run regression to predict test response from socioeconomic status or you want to know how much of the test response variation is explained by socioeconomic status, then $y$ should be test outcome and $x$ should be socioeconomic status.

However, if you want to run regression to predict socioeconomic status from mental ability or you want to know how much of socioeconomic status is explained by mental ability, then $y$ should be socioeconomic status and $x$ should be test outcome.

And if you just want to know if both variables are correlated, don't worry, because correlation of $x$ and $y$ is the same as correlation of $y$ and $x$.